# Picklist value is not getting displayed

Tags: picklist, case-object

Can anyone help me on this?

I have a requirement ,when we click on the closecase button for the closer of single case in that page,we would like to replace the piccoloist data type field as "Reason for Resolution" instead of Case Reason.We have replaced the field in the "Close Case layout".

The issue is when we select a case and go for the closer of the case in that page the piccoloist data type Field gets displayed but the drop down values are not getting displayed .
[image]
Note : I have 6 different Record types and 10 page layout is been used.The piccoloist data type field "Reason For Resolution " is available for all the record types nd in page layout.

My concern is why the drop down values are not getting displayed.
 Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: is this standard Reason field on your custom field? Make sure you have option value in that.

Comment: Please check the access on profile or any validaion rule on the object.

Comment: Make sure you have picklist OPTIONS assigned to the record type as well.

Comment: this is not an issue with profile as field label is visible.

Comment: @Himanshu,@Santanu Halder ,@ Kushal gupte :Thanks for your respose.It is a Custom field with piccoloist data type.When i checked for the different Record types i could see the field been their and for one record type this piccoloist values have not been selected.It is Mandatory that all the Record Types should have all the piccoloist field assigned.

Comment: have you added option value in that picklist it seems like that picklist doesn't contain any value

Comment: @Himanshu:One of the Record type ,didn't had the piccoloist values been selected to the field.Thanks for your time and needful help.